# how can i print the value or equation that is performing in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have an if-statement that says

```
if f1_date == f2_date:    
    if f2_number > f1_number:
        print('WIN')
        continue
    elif f2_number <= f1_number:
        print('lose')
```

Can I print the part of the statement that says `if f2_number > f1_number`, so for example, if there's a row where `f1_number = 1000` and `f2_number = 2000` then is there a way to print out just `1000` or `2000 > 1000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)** syntax to get your desired output (modify as required):

```
from datetime import datetime

f1_date = f2_date = datetime.now()
f1_number, f2_number = 1000, 2000

if f1_date == f2_date:    
    if f2_number > f1_number:
        print(f"out just {f1_number} or {f2_number} > {f1_number}")
        print('WIN')
    elif f2_number <= f1_number:
        print('LOSE')
```

**Output:**

```
out just 1000 or 2000 > 1000
WIN
```